# How to filter by grouped dates when using date type data from a SSAS Cube in Excel

Tags: excel, date, filter, ssas, cube

I have a published SSAS cube with multiple facts, dimensions, and a date table. We have end users that would like to filter some of the data by different dates that are on the dimensions (service date, bill date, etc.). In the SSAS model, all of the columns containing those dates have a short date data type. However, when I pull those columns into a pivot table in an excel document, the dates are not grouped and you have to select each day one at a time.

I tried to change up the date format, but no matter what I do it does not group the date columns when getting data from the SSAS cube.

Here is a screenshot of the data type in SSAS:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the filter:

[image]

This is what I am trying to get to:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a hierarchy containing attributes Year, Month, and Day.

In my cube it looks like this:

[image: Demonstration of answer]